# Getting the innerText

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have an xml file like this:

```
<locations>
    <location country="UK">
        <name>London</name>
        <class>Silver</class>
    </location>
    <location country="Germany">
        <name>Berlin II</name>
        <class>Bronze</class>
    </location>
</locations>
```

When opening a page I deduct a value "currentCountry" from the URL. Now I want to use that value to search the XML file for the corresponding `location` entry and put the innerHtml value of its child nodes into variable. This is my current code, which is not working so far:

```
string currentCountry = "Germany" //For testing purposes
string currentName = "";
string currentClass = "";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\IIS\\Web\\Content\\locations.xml");

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/locations/location[@country='" + currentCountry + "']");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    currentName = xn.SelectSingleNode("/name").InnerText;
    currentClass = xn.SelectSingleNode("/class").InnerText;
}
```

I get the error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` pointing to the first line inside the `foreach` loop.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

Remove forwardslash and it should work just fine:

```
  currentName = xn.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
                currentClass = xn.SelectSingleNode("class").InnerText;
```

Comment: I think the solution I found is even simpler because it doesn't require another select, but your help is highly appreciated regardless. Thank you.

Comment: Its always a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simply using `currentName = xn["name"].InnerText;` works just fine. Found it literally 10 seconds after posting here :/

Comment: So you did no research before posting? =(

Comment: I did research, got stuck, posted my question, and continued my research. It was sheer luck I stumbled upon the solution right after I posted here.